# Estoy tratando de cambiar los nombres de unos carros por números en pandas

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("./Auto_MPG_Data.csv")
df[0:5]
df_modify=df.copy()
print(df_modify['Car name'].value_counts())
for i,element in enumerate(range(len(list(df_modify['Car name'].unique())))):
    df_modify['Car_name']=df_modify['Car name'].replace(element,i, inplace=True)
df_prt2[300:350]
```

Existen nombres repetidos, entonces quiero crear un loop que me ayude a indentificar cuales están repetidos y los cambie por su  número correspondiente junto a los demás.
Sin embargo, al finalizar en la nueva columna me sale "None" en vez de i. No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo de una manera más eficiente podemos hacer uso de un lambda y numpy. Te explico:

Llamamos las librerías que necesitamos

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np #Numpy es útil porque vamos a realizar concatenación y range
```

Recreé tu dataframe con algunos ejemplos de tu imagen para poder realizar el ejercicio:

```
# Datos de ejemplo
d = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Car name': ['cutlass', 'cutlass', 'cutlass', 'plymouth', 'datsun', 'datsun', 'vw rabbit', 'datsun 310'],
     'Cylinders': [8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 10, 12]
    }
)
```

Así queda el dataframe:

```
Car name    Cylinders
0   cutlass     8
1   cutlass     9
2   cutlass     10
3   plymouth    12
4   datsun      14
5   datsun      11
6   vw rabbit   10
7   datsun 310  12
```

Pandas tiene una opción poderosa llamada groupyby para poder agrupar los datos y combinándolo con lambda podemos recorrer todas tus filas

```
d.groupby('Car name')['Car name'].apply(lambda n: n + np.concatenate(([''], (np.arange(len(n))+1).astype(str)[1:])))
```

El resultado será que mantendrás el nombre de los autos pero le agregaremos un número identificador:

```
0       cutlass
1      cutlass2
2      cutlass3
3      plymouth
4        datsun
5       datsun2
6     vw rabbit
7    datsun 310
```

El código completo sería:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Datos de ejemplo
d = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Car name': ['cutlass', 'cutlass', 'cutlass', 'plymouth', 'datsun', 'datsun', 'vw rabbit', 'datsun 310'],
     'Cylinders': [8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 10, 12]
    }
)
d.groupby('Car name')['Car name'].apply(lambda n: n + np.concatenate(([''], (np.arange(len(n))+1).astype(str)[1:])))
```